# vue.js Как правильно сделать сортировку, и вывести вложенные таблицы?

Tags: сортировка, vue.js, frontend, table

Всем доброго вечера.
Есть 2 таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Одна идет как дополнение другой, и у них есть одинаковые столбцы orderdate, которые собственно содержат даты заказов.
Через vue.js нужно вывести таблицы так, чтобы они выводились вместе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот код выводи неверно. Просто выводится вся таблица ordersperdate после каждой даты из orders.

```html
<div>
    <div>
          <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr class="table-active">
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Cancelled</th>
              <th>Reserved</th>
              <th>Delivered</th>
              <th>Summ</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="column in orders">
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">{{column.orderdate}}</button></td>
              <td>{{column.cancelled}}</td>
              <td>{{column.reserved}}</td>
              <td>{{column.delivered}}</td>
              <td>{{column.ordersumm}}</td>
      
                <table class="table table-bordered" >
                  <thead>
                    <tr class="table-active">
                      <th>Orderdate</th>
                      <th>Orderid</th>
                      <th>Storeid</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="column in ordersperdate" >
                      <td>{{column.orderdate}}</td>
                      <td>{{column.orderid}}</td>
                      <td>{{column.storeid}}</td>
                      <td>{{column.status}}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table> 
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Прошу помощи у спецов по vue.js
[Ославляю ссылку на fiddle, с введенными данными](https://jsfiddle.net/VeVeO/pz7aboek/15/)

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Это что надо несколько таблиц?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для объединения таблиц можно использовать вычисляемые [свойства](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), после чего вывести в цикле подтаблицы и их строки привычным способом.

Для того, чтобы можно было вывести значения колонок при разных названиях ключей в объекте, я преобразовал стоки таблицы из объектов в [массивы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), после чего доступ к полю можно получить, используя цифровой индекс.

Неудобно, что количество столбцов в таблицах не совпадает.

Готовый пример:

```js
  new Vue({
    el: '#orders-table',
    data: {
      orders: [{
        "orderdate": "21.05.2018",
        "cancelled": 4,
        "reserved": 13,
        "delivered": 0,
        "ordersumm": 17
      }, {
        "orderdate": "20.05.2018",
        "cancelled": 22,
        "reserved": 72,
        "delivered": 2,
        "ordersumm": 96
      }, {
        "orderdate": "19.05.2018",
        "cancelled": 14,
        "reserved": 45,
        "delivered": 3,
        "ordersumm": 62
      }, {
        "orderdate": "18.05.2018",
        "cancelled": 97,
        "reserved": 25,
        "delivered": 1,
        "ordersumm": 93
      }],
      ordersperdate: [{
        "orderdate": "21.05.2018",
        "orderid": 357903677,
        "storeid": 10251,
        "status": "Готов к выдаче"
      }, {
        "orderdate": "20.05.2018",
        "orderid": 342344234,
        "storeid": 10251,
        "status": "Отменен"
      }, {
        "orderdate": "20.05.2018",
        "orderid": 423423425,
        "storeid": 10251,
        "status": "Готов к выдаче"
      }, {
        "orderdate": "19.05.2018",
        "orderid": 342342425,
        "storeid": 10251,
        "status": "Выдан"
      }, {
        "orderdate": "19.05.2018",
        "orderid": 324234243,
        "storeid": 10251,
        "status": "Отменен"
      }, {
        "orderdate": "19.05.2018",
        "orderid": 213123121,
        "storeid": 10251,
        "status": "Выдан"
      }, {
        "orderdate": "19.05.2018",
        "orderid": 255554422,
        "storeid": 10251,
        "status": "Готов к выдаче"
      }, {
        "orderdate": "18.05.2018",
        "orderid": 876697795,
        "storeid": 10251,
        "status": "Отменен"
      }, {
        "orderdate": "18.05.2018",
        "orderid": 342566635,
        "storeid": 10251,
        "status": "Готов к выдаче"
      }, {
        "orderdate": "18.05.2018",
        "orderid": 342556262,
        "storeid": 10251,
        "status": "Выдан"
      }, {
        "orderdate": "18.05.2018",
        "orderid": 768668565,
        "storeid": 10251,
        "status": "Отменен"
      }]
    },
    computed: {
      tables() {
        let result = [];

        for (let line of this.orders) {
          let group = this.ordersperdate.filter(date => date.orderdate == line.orderdate);
          group.push(line)
          result.push(group.map( table => Object.values(table) ))
        }

        return result;
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="orders-table">
  <div v-for="table in tables">
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>orderdate</th>
          <th>Orderid</th>
          <th>Storeid</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(row, indexRow) in table">
            <td v-for="(column, indexColumn) in row">{{column}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Nic34/pz7aboek/17/

Answer (score 1):

В голову пришло еще одно решение, которое я реализовал за 5 минут. 
Нужно данные из таблиц объединить в одну структуру.
Прислал себе в виде JSON, и спокойно разобрал, распределил, без создания новых функций.